# how to insert/update/delete on columns with index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I had to index some of my cells in multiple tables to improve speed.

Now how i should change my insert/update/delete etc queries to make sure indexing works?

What exactly i should do and what happens if i just don't do anything special?

Should i just automate re indexing of columns every hour ?

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL RDBMS will handle the indexing for you.  `DELETE`s, `INSERT`s, and `UPDATE`s will modify the index without any action from you.  Re-indexing them should not ever become necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Database will keep your indexes up to date.

You don't need to change your queries. RDBMS will determine when to use index.

To make sure RDBMS uses indexes in your `SELECT`/`UPDATE` queries use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) (For UPDATE queries, just put your WHERE clause to `SELECT` for `EXPLAIN`)

Comment: what you mean "For UPDATE queries, just put your WHERE clause to SELECT for EXPLAIN"

Comment: If you want to check if `UPDATE t SET  ... WHERE s` statement is using index execute `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t WHERE s` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

MY test code: 
 Differents 42 sec and 2 min .

```
mysql> UPDATE  big_table SET id = INSERT(id,1,5,'');
Query OK, 2835999 rows affected (42.69 sec)
Rows matched: 2835999  Changed: 2835999  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE big_table ADD INDEX id(id);
Query OK, 2835999 rows affected (5.75 sec)
Records: 2835999  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE  big_table SET id = INSERT(id,1,4,'');
Query OK, 2835999 rows affected, 2856 warnings (2 min 1.49 sec)
Rows matched: 2835999  Changed: 2835999  Warnings: 2856
```